# Error while reading file, its storing alternate line data

Tags: c++

this is my code, when i am reading the lines which must be stored in the class, its reading one line and storing the value of next line, I am unable to identify my mistake in the code. Please help me to correct it. the task is to skip the lines that has sentences and read the lines which has data abd store it in the class variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class data_Read
{
public:
    /* timestamp */
    double time;

    /*state of the signal 1 or 2*/
    unsigned int state;

    /*ID in hexadecimal and converted to decimal*/
    std::string  ID;

    /* Received or transmitted message */
    std::string status;

    /* Message type */
    std::string type;

    /* byte length */
    unsigned int byte_lent;

    /* CAN Message */
    std::string message_1;
    std::string message_2;
    std::string message_3;
    std::string message_4;
    std::string message_5;
    std::string message_6;
    std::string message_7;
    std::string message_8;

    std::string type1;
    std::string type2;
    std::string type3;
    std::string type4;
    std::string type5;
    std::string type6;
    std::string type7;
    std::string type8;
    std::string type9;

};

int main()
{

    std::ifstream ifs("datatrace.txt");
    data_Read data;
    std::string line;

    while (!ifs.eof())
    {

    start:
        std::getline(ifs, line);

        std::cout << line << std::endl;


        if (!isspace(line[0]))
        {
            goto start;
        }
        std::size_t space = line.find(" ", 0);
        if (space == 0)
        {
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
            {
                if (isalpha(line[i]))
                {
                    goto start;
                }   
            }


                    ifs >> data.time >> data.state >> data.ID >> data.status >> data.type >> data.byte_lent >> data.CAN_message_1 >> data.CAN_message_2 >> data.CAN_message_3 >> data.CAN_message_4 >> data.CAN_message_5 >> data.CAN_message_6;
    ifs >> data.CAN_message_7 >> data.CAN_message_8 >> data.type1 >> data.type2 >> data.type3 >> data.type4 >> data.type5 >> data.type6 >> data.type7>> data.type8 >> data.type9;
    cout << data.time << "\t" << data.state << "\t" << data.ID << "\t" << data.status << "\t" << data.type << "\t" << data.byte_lent << "\t" << data.CAN_message_1 << "\t" << data.CAN_message_2 << "\t" << data.CAN_message_3 << "\t";
    cout << data.CAN_message_4 << "\t"<< data.CAN_message_5 << "\t"<< data.CAN_message_6 << "\t" << data.CAN_message_7 << "\t"<< data.CAN_message_8 << "\t"<< data.type1 << "\t"<< data.type2 << "\t"<< data.type3 << "\t"<< data.type4 << "\t"<< data.type5 << "\t" << data.type6 << "\t"<< data.type7 << "\t"<< data.type8 << "\t"<< data.type9 << endl;          
        }
    }
    ifs.close();
    return 0;
}
```

and the text file contain

```
date Fri Sep 1 02:11:40.195 pm 2017
base hex  timestamps absolute
internal events logged
// version 9.0.0
Begin Triggerblock Fri Sep 1 02:11:40.195 pm 2017
   0.000000 Start of measurement
   0.002893 1  201             Rx   d 8 06 0D 00 B0 89 00 0D E7  Length = 227925 BitCount = 118 ID = 513
   0.003133 1  280             Rx   d 8 1B 0C 7C F1 E8 75 39 67  Length = 221910 BitCount = 115 ID = 640
   0.006981 CAN 1 Status:chip status error active
   0.006981 CAN 2 Status:chip status error active
   0.007123 1  244             Rx   d 8 7B 01 00 08 80 80 C0 00  Length = 233925 BitCount = 121 ID = 580
   0.007148 2  B2              Rx   d 8 C0 13 9A 13 D8 13 C0 13  Length = 221910 BitCount = 115 ID = 178
   0.007359 1  246             Rx   d 8 55 01 00 49 50 B6 7A 89  Length = 217925 BitCount = 113 ID = 582
   0.007394 2  86              Rx   d 8 62 00 2A 20 01 84 02 00  Length = 225925 BitCount = 117 ID = 134
```

Comment: `goto` inside a `while` loop is asking for trouble. At first glance I think your `std::getline` should be before your `start` identifier else the next line gets read.

Comment: but if i put before start it does not fetch next line, what to do

Comment: i also used line.clear() before each goto statement, still not working

Comment: Debugging is the process of stepping through the running application line-by-line seeing what happens. Rather do that to see when the line is being read when you didn't expect it to be. By putting in statements like `clear` you are just hoping for a coincidental fix, debugging will instead help you understand.

Comment: can you help me out with the changes in the code, i am trying as you said but its not working, i maybe wrong somewhere

Comment: i checked it when it fetch line 0.002893 it check for the sentence when that loop  fails it goes to the storing part and store 0.003133 line

Comment: Both `std::getline` and `ifs >>` reads from the file stream. So where you `ifs >>` you are reading from where `getline` finished, ie the next line. Rather extract the fields from your `line` variable.

Comment: i am very sorry to ask you again can you write that code part, so that i be fully clear.

Comment: and the changes i should actually make in code so that it works

Comment: thanks a lot i am finally able to get the output as required as per your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
the final answer 

while (std::getline(file, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);

        std::size_t space = line.find(" ", 0);
        if (!isspace(line[0]))
        {
            iss.clear();
        }
        else
        {
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i <= 12; i++)
            {
                if (isalpha(line[i]))
                {
                    iss.clear();
                    goto start;
                }
            }

            iss >> data.time >> data.state >> data.ID >> data.status >> data.type >> data.byte_lent >> data.CAN_message_1 >> data.CAN_message_2 >> data.CAN_message_3 >> data.CAN_message_4 >> data.CAN_message_5 >> data.CAN_message_6;
            iss >> data.CAN_message_7 >> data.CAN_message_8 >> data.type1 >> data.type2 >> data.type3 >> data.type4 >> data.type5 >> data.type6 >> data.type7 >> data.type8 >> data.type9;
```